# How to pass data from one page to another using javascript without local storage

Tags: javascript, html

How do i pass data from one HTML page to multiple HTML pages using JavaScript but without using local storage.

Comment: It seems incomplete question to me.. "What have you tried ?" will make us understand your requirement better...

Comment: by using Local Storage i had tried, But the task is with out using local storage is  there any procedure

Comment: it would be helpful for us to help you if you could show us what have you coded and it's not working

Comment: While I agree the question is incomplete, you could take a look at query strings and hash values.

Comment: Besides query strings and hash values as mentioned before, cookies may also be an option

Comment: The question is are you trying to pass data on the same domain, just between opened tabs? Like sending data from mysite.com/home to mysite.com/profile (that's where localstorage will be enough), but if you want to transfer data between different domains, you will need to send data as parameters in http request or use external backend service like firebase and connect both websites to the same database.

Answer (score 1):

Two Ways To Pass Data :

1).Local Storage / Session Storage

2).Cookies.

Cookies Reference Link : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

possibly if you want to just transfer data to be used by JavaScript then you can use Hash Tags like this

http://localhost/project/index.html#exist
so once when you are done retriving the data show the message and change the window.location.hash to a suitable value.. now whenever you ll refresh the page the hashtag wont be present

NOTE: when you will use this instead ot query strings the data being sent cannot be retrived/read by the server

Comment: Why use hashtags when you have parameters?

Comment: I am providing him all the options.He will choose what ever he want.query string is also an option.

Comment: But why would you prefer hashtags over parameters?

Comment: There is no point of preference here.Just providing him some useful information.

Comment: If there is point of preference, i will prefer local/session storage first.But he dont want to use those concepts.

Answer (score 1):

you can use url get variables. mypage.html?x=value&y=othervalue.

```
var url = location.href //gets the current URL
var request = {}; //sets array
var pairs = url.substring(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&'); //obtains parameters

for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
    if(pairs[i]) {
        var pair = pairs[i].split('=');
        request[decodeURIComponent(pair[0])] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
     }
}
```

you now have an array of all the parameters. in this case the array should contain x=value, y=othervalue

if you want to pass data from one page to another you make sure that the url you are navigating to contains the parameters you want the next page to have.

more info:
[Make a JavaScript array from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297765/make-a-javascript-array-from-url)

Comment: its okay...But i got the output by use these type.But it is also the wrong way he told.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you open a page using JavaScript

```
window.open("http://www.yourpage.com");
```

Keep a reference for each window you open

```
var w = window.open("http://www.yourpage.com");
```

If you have variable "data" on the page you just opened

```
w.data = 'your-data-goes-here';
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at :

use cookies : 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript)

or make rediects with get params :

```
 window.location = '/fooUrl?fooParam=' + fooValue;
```

and then you can use : window.location.search to get this value .

see: [How to retrieve GET parameters from javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript)

But in my opinion this is really dirty way , if no code we can't do magic , so post your code ...