# Decode JSON, including array from URL paramter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, object, url, get

I have this URL:

```
http://localhost:5000/?orderID=000000034&fullname=Leonard+Niehaus&email=test%40gmail.com&items%5B0%5D%5BitemId%5D=9&items%5B0%5D%5Btitle%5D=Joghurt&items%5B0%5D%5Bqty%5D=1.0000&items%5B1%5D%5BitemId%5D=8&items%5B1%5D%5Btitle%5D=Alpenmilch&items%5B1%5D%5Bqty%5D=1.0000
```

Now I'm trying to encode the URL to an Object. This is my current attempt:

```
function URLToArray(url) {
  var request = {};
  var pairs = url.substring(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
  for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
      if(!pairs[i])
          continue;
      var pair = pairs[i].split('=');
      request[decodeURIComponent(pair[0])] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
   }
   return request;
}
```

However I need this function to return the array as a JSON array, and not the way it currently does:

[image: Screenshot of object]

How do I get my function to return my object array?

Comment: Can you show your own code attempt and not the copy/paste job in place presently from this SO link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297765/make-a-javascript-array-from-url

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first get the object with [help from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript).

Example using [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) with a regular expression loop:

```js
const url = "http://localhost:5000/?orderID=000000034&fullname=Leonard+Niehaus&email=test%40gmail.com&items%5B0%5D%5BitemId%5D=9&items%5B0%5D%5Btitle%5D=Joghurt&items%5B0%5D%5Bqty%5D=1.0000&items%5B1%5D%5BitemId%5D=8&items%5B1%5D%5Btitle%5D=Alpenmilch&items%5B1%5D%5Bqty%5D=1.0000";

const regex = /^([a-z0-9]+)?\[([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\]*/mi;

function URLToArray(url) {
 url = decodeURIComponent(url);
  const args = new URLSearchParams(url.split('?')[1]);
  
  let request = {};
  args.forEach((value, key) => {
   let baseKey = key;
    let ogValue = value;
    let lastKey = '';
   while ((m = regex.exec(key)) !== null) {
     if (m[1]) {
       baseKey = m[1];
        value = request[baseKey] || {};
       request[baseKey] = value;
      }
      
      if (m[2]) {
       value = value[lastKey] || value;
        value[m[2]] = value[m[2]] || {};
       lastKey = m[2];
      }
      
      key = key.replace(m[0], '');
    }
    
    if (lastKey) {
     value[lastKey] = ogValue;
    } else {
     request[baseKey] = value;
    }
  });
  return request;
}

console.log(URLToArray(url));
```

This isn't perfect you will be left with nested objects as opposed to proper arrays for your `items`, and there are likely libraries that can achieve the same result better.