# How can I get url of this request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, request

I need get URL to create iframe to download file.
I tried to print resp.data, but it doesn't works.

```
Workers.query({
    "id": $scope.currentUser.uuid,

  },
    function(resp){
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
      iframe.setAttribute("src", "myUrlHere");
      iframe.setAttribute("style", "display: none");
      document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    },
    function(resp){
      alert('failed');
    }
  );
```

Comment: Can you explain your problem with your question title? Do you want to get any para from GET?

Comment: Sorry, I want to get url of request which I did in my code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read get request using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209052/how-to-read-get-request-using-javascript)

Comment: unfortunately not, window.location will give me only http://192.168.2.145:8383/#!/reports, request url should be like: http://192.168.2.145:8383/reports/pdf/xxx/xxx/

Comment: `window.location` will return full path, that you can see in the URL bar of browser

Comment: yeah, I know, but It's not the full url as I said

Comment: run `window.location.href` on browser console, And check the output is correct?

Comment: the same result

Comment: Then you should use `Angularjs`'s `$location`

Comment: The same, I only gets  192.168.2.145:8383/#!/reports, without /pdf/xxx/xxx/, I must do this manually somehow. Thanks for help, If you get the idea let me know